# Can I create an index on a field to speed up searching?

Tags: filters, indexing, custom-index

I have a large table (10's of millions of records), I want to be able to filter reasonable quickly, can I create an index on a field to help speed up fitlering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit a Case through the Salesforce Success Community to have Salesforce index a field.  Also, assigning a field as an ExternalId will index it.

EDIT: Found the documentation regarding External IDs: [Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm)

Comment: will indexing the field in general make a different to report performance? is this the best thing to do to speed up filtering?

Comment: Yes, it will definitely improve performance for any **selective** query.  I guess it depends on how you're doing your filtering, but typically indexing will always help performance.

Comment: And if you aren't familiar with what "selective" means in the Salesforce query game, look here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-make-my-SOQL-query-selective-And-the-process-to-determine-the-fields-that-can-be-custom-indexed&language=en_US

Comment: This cheatsheet helps tremendesly when working with Large Data Voluume (LDV) objects in Salesforce.com - https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: This document is a must read also if you are dealing with LDV on Force.com. http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf . It covers additional topics like Skinny Tables, etc which you often have to enable for LDV datasets.